# How can we cache index in MongoDB 3.2?

Tags: mongodb, caching, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am trying to load GeoSpatial index in to RAM\Cache. I tried touch command:

```
db.runCommand({ touch: "businesspoints", data: false, index: true });
```

But it throws error that:

```
{
"ok" : 0.0,
"errmsg" : "this storage engine does not support touch",
"code" : 115
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely using the WiredTiger storage engine, which is the default in MongoDB 3.2. The touch command only works on the mmapv1 storage engine. See also the documentation at https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/command/touch/

Comment: Yes, I am using Wire dTiger, is there any way to cache index in WiredTiger ?

Comment: My understanding is that the engine caches data and indexes automatically. A configurable option would be --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB but this does not really help your question.